# Refreshing the record detail page after salesforce flow ends / lightning:availableForFlowActions not working

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I have a couple of flows being started from a button in a record detail layout in Salesforce. When the flow ends I would like to see the record refresh automatically. I've tried the [Unofficial SF](https://unofficialsf.com/update-screen/) solution which didn't work for me as I couldn't get the aura component to appear as a Code Action...so I tried [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301086/refresh-the-page-after-the-flow-completes) instead...with the same results.
I really don't know what might I be doing wrong here
[image: My component]
Name is RefreshView.cmp

And this is what I see when searching for it:
[image: no results]

I tried:

- Changing the API version
- Checking if 'Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows' is set in Process Automation
- Adding access="global" to the component
- Tried with both autolaunched and screen flows

I'm at a loss here...
Can anyone help?